# JS. Как обращаться к вложенным функциям?

Tags: javascript

**Как обратиться к вложенной функции и вложенной в нее функции?**

Здравствуйте! У меня возник вопрос: как мне обратиться к функции second и как обратиться к функции third.
К third, как Вы можете заметить, нужно обратиться с аргументом = 1.

```
function first(){
    console.log('1 function - completed');

    function second(){
        console.log('2 function - completed');

        function third(arg){
            if (arg == 1) {
                console.log('3 function - completed');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что значит _обратиться к вложенной функции_?

Comment: Обратиться значит вызвать

Comment: вызвать в каком месте?

Comment: За пределами всех этих функций

Comment: за пределами функции нельзя обратиться к ее локальным переменным

Comment: Мне как-то раз надо было изменить код функции на сайте, добавив туда ссылку на свою функцию и эта функция с сайта причем периодически менялась, поэтому я брал текст функции с помощью toString(), потом регуляркой выдергивал тело и передаваемые параметры, добавлял в начало свою функцию и передавал ей все эти параметры и вешал обратно на эту функцию свой вариант. В принципе таким методом можно выдрать и внутреннюю функцию, извращение конечно, но все же:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function first() {
  console.log('1 function - completed');

  return function second() {
    console.log('2 function - completed');

    return function third(arg) {
      if (arg == 1) {
        console.log('3 function - completed');
      }
    }
  }
}

first()()(1)
```

или вот так:

```js
function first() {
  console.log('1 function - completed');

  function second() {
    console.log('2 function - completed');

    function third(arg) {
      if (arg == 1) {
        console.log('3 function - completed');
      }
    }
    third(1);
  }
  second();
}

first();
```

смотря что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно через замыкание

```
function first(){
console.log('1 function - completed');

return function(){
    console.log('2 function - completed');

    return function(arg){
        if (arg == 1) {
            console.log('3 function - completed');
        }
    }
  }
}
let f = first();
f()(1);
```